# Return multiple values from function in an assigment

Tags: javascript

If I want to return a multiple values from a function, in an assigment, do I need to use an intermediate array to receive those values?

How am I used to do it in JavaScript:

```js
  let f = () => return [1, 2, 3];
  let a, b, c, arr;
  arr = f();
  a = arr[0]; b = arr[1]; c = arr[2]
```

Is JavaScript like C, returning assignment to the first lhand operator, or is it possible to do something more flexible, like in this example from Ruby (without using loop):

```rb
  def f
    return 1, 2, 3
  end
  a, b, c = f
```

My motivation is simply lack of readability in the JavaScript method.

Comment: Which part lacks readability? `return [1, 2, 3]` is about as readable as it gets: return an array consisting of those three literal values.

Comment: The assignment part, not the return. Destructuring assignment was what I was looking for, I did't  know it can apply to arrays as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues**

1. `return` not needed in simple [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax)
2. [destructure assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax

```js
let f = () => [1, 2, 3];
let [a, b, c] = f();

console.log(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get values from an array either using `index` or using `destructuring` . If there are multiple values then you can easily `destructure` and store it in different variables in a single statement.

```js
let f = () => [1, 2, 3];

//Using Destructuring
const [a, b, c] = f();
console.log(a, b, c);

// Accessing using index
const arr = f();
const m = arr[0];
const n = arr[1];
const o = arr[2];
console.log(m, n, o);
```

Since you are using an array to return multiple values then you can use either implicitly return in a function of you can explicitly return an array from it

**`1) Explicitly return`**

```js
let f = () => {
  return [1, 2, 3];
};

const [a, b, c] = f();
console.log(a, b, c);
```

**`2) Implicitly return`**

```js
let f = () => [1, 2, 3];

const [a, b, c] = f();
console.log(a, b, c);
```